# windows updated, grub menu is gone

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I have/had dual boot with 11.10 and windows 7.  I left my laptop running with windows 7 going and I think it did an automatic update and restarted it's self.  Now when I turn it on all I get is a black screen with the blinking cursor in the corner.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another computer available you could make a live DVD or usb, boot into it and install boot repair (onto the live usb) by running the commands below. Once installed tell it to re-wright the grub onto the HDD and make sure it doesn't write it onto the live DVD or USB stick.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for more infomation on how to use boot-repair.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I have a live usb that I made last week just incase I ever needed it.

Comment: If you need any more help or guidence, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

so the windows update finished succesfully? you can try with super grub2 disk http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ to restore your grub and boot ubuntu if it was only a failure with windows update. Maybe then you can try to repair your windows installation from ubuntu or from a livecd